# How to remove bootstrap from Laravel 7 properly?

Tags: laravel

This is my first time I'm using Laravel. When `laravel new <project>` is executed, it automatically contains:

- bootstrap folder
- bootstrap.js
- `require('./bootstrap');` in app.js

My package.json file

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"
    }
}
```

How do I remove/uninstall it? I don't need Bootstrap since I already have Tailwind to deal with CSS. I don't want unused file laying around in my project. Thanks.

Comment: `require('./bootstrap');` this is not bootstrap  it for load all the mxins in laravel app

Comment: can u add your `package.json` code in here.?

Comment: added package.json code

Comment: don't worry u don't have `bootstrap` installed LOL as it is not in `package.json`

Comment: So the bootstrap actually means something else rather than the actual css framework?

Comment: yes it is diffrent

Comment: Well that explains everything then. Thanks!